# Set timeout for user defined function using cancelation token

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, async-await, cancellation-token

I want to cancel a Task if it lasts longer than 3 seconds.

First attempt:

```
public static async Task DoSomething()
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
}

var task1 = DoSomething();
var task2 = Task.Delay(3000);

Task.WaitAny(task1, task2);
```

Second attempt:

I tried to use `cancellationToken` but it does not seems to work. It waits for the function 10 seconds and it seems it ignores the 3 seconds delayed cancellation.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = cts.Token;
cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

await Task.Run(async () => await DoSomething(), token);
```

Can someone help me with implementing such functionality using `cancellationToken`?

Comment: Cancellation in .NET [is cooperative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads). You can cancel something if it supports cancellation, otherwise, you can't. You can cancel the awaiting of the operation, like you did in your example, but not the operation itself.

Comment: Oh, that is It thanks for answer, so I can use cancelation token only If function natively support It

Comment: Yeap Tigran, exactly. Also congrats for your victory against Mikhail Botvinnik! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `CancellationToken` to `DoSomething` and use it there:

```
public static async Task DoSomething(CancellationToken t)
{
    await Task.Delay(10000, t);
}

var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = cts.Token;
cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
try
{
    await Task.Run(async () => await DoSomething(token), token);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
{
    // canceled
}
```

From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation):

> When a task instance observes an OperationCanceledException thrown by user code, it compares the exception's token to its associated token (the one that was passed to the API that created the Task). If they are the same and the token's IsCancellationRequested property returns true, the task interprets this as acknowledging cancellation and transitions to the Canceled state. If you do not use a Wait or WaitAll method to wait for the task, then the task just sets its status to Canceled.

But it seems `Task` transitions to `Canceled` independent of if the same token is provided or not.

The only difference I could find between passing token to `Task.Run` or not was that if cancellation is requested before the task begins execution, the task does not execute, instead it is set to the `Canceled` state and throws a `TaskCanceledException` exception.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but It is not what I want. You are calling function task.delay which natively has parameter cancelationtoken, what If function is doing some actions which has no support of cancelation token

Comment: Oh, my question is already answered by  Theodor Zoulias